# python unhandled exception

Tags: python, scripting, xml-parsing

I am working with **MODO** python scripts. I  imported the MODO setting data into **.cfg**  file with the **XML format** .

My .cfg file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <camera>
     <Position>
       <X>
        2.0
       </X>
       <Y>
        0.75
       </Y>
       <Z>
        4.0
       </Z>
     </Position>
               "
               "
           so on......
```

Now,i wanted to export this file into my **MODO** application.So,i need to parse this .**cfg** file (xml format).

I tried this:

```
#python

 import lx

 import xml.dom.minidom
 from xml.dom.minidom import Node
 dom1 = xml.dom.minidom.parse("c:\myfile.cfg")
```

When i try to run this script in my MODO application,it gives me following error:

[image]

Line 26 is `dom1 = xml.dom.minidom.parse("c:\myfile.cfg")`

How do i parse my .cfg  file with xml format using **minidom** object in **python** ???
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pretty good example on Python [mindom documentation page](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) you can also consider using JSON which is easier to write, or serialise Python objects to JSON.